# Is there a way to create AWS Dashboard using cloudformation or AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I wanted to create an AWS Dashboard using cloudformation but did find a way.
Guess AWS has not yet added support for that.

As an alternative is it possible to create that using AWS CLI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS just announced support for this.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-api-cloudformation-support-for-amazon-cloudwatch-dashboards/

CloudFormation documentation is also available: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-dashboard.html

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct your question is concerns [Resource Groups](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/what-are-resource-groups/). It is not possible at this time to create Resource Group in Cloud Formation Templates or via the awscli.

[Resource Groups](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/what-are-resource-groups/) are tied to a User, not an account - so it's not possible to define them at an account level and allow Users to access them.

It's possible for a User to '[Share](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/managing-resource-groups.html#sharing-a-resource-group)' a Resource Group they've created by passing a URL to another User.

Comment: No. I want to create the AWS Cloudwatch Dashboard using cloudformation. But I guess I found out that they so not have support yet for doing that via the cloudformation